# Projective Transform - matlab code

Tags: image-processing, matlab

i can't use any toolbox function i need to build it from scratch.

```
% load images
img1 = readImage('roadSign.tif');
img2 = readImage('lena.tif');

% call the main function  
mapIntoImage(img1,img2)


function    [newImage] = mapIntoImage(imageA,imageB)
%  Input:      imageA, imageB - a grayscale image in the range [0..255].
% 
%  Output:    newImage – imageA into which image B has been mapped.
% 
showImage(imageA)
hold on
% Initially, the list of points is empty.
xy = [];
% Loop, picking up the points.
disp('Please enter corners of place to insert image in clockwise order.')

for j = 1:4
   [xi,yi] = ginput(1);
   %draw a yellow dot
   plot(xi,yi,'yo')
   xy(:,j) = [xi;yi];
end

% get x1 y1 cordinates  - xy(:, 1)

imgRow = size(imageB,1);
imgCol = size(imageB,2);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:imgCol,1:imgRow);

imgBcords = [0 size(imageB, 1) size(imageB,1) 0 ;
        0 0 size(imageB,2) size(imageB,2)];
coefs = findCoefficients(xy, imgBcords);

A = [coefs(1) coefs(2) coefs(5);coefs(3) coefs(4) coefs(6); coefs(7) coefs(8) 1];

temp = zeros(size(X,1), size(X,2), 3);
new = ones(256);
for i = 1:size(X,1)
    for j = 1:size(X,2)
        temp(i,j,:) =A*[X(i,j); Y(i,j); new(i,j)];
end
end

end 

function [ result ] = findCoefficients( imageA, imageB )
% finds coefficients for inverse mapping algorithem 
%   takes 2 X 2d vectors each consists of 4 points x,y
%   and returns the coef accroding to reverse mapping function
%
% x y 0 0 1 0 -xx' -yx'
% 0 0 x y 0 1 -xy' -yy'  
%                       y' and x' are in the destenation picture;


A = [imageB(1,1) imageB(2,1) 0 0 1 0 -imageB(1,1)*imageA(1,1) -imageB(2,1)*imageA(1,1); 
    0 0 imageB(1,1) imageB(2,1) 0 1 -imageB(1,1)*imageA(2,1) -imageB(2,1)*imageA(2,1);
imageB(1,2) imageB(2,2) 0 0 1 0 -imageB(1,2)*imageA(1,2) -imageB(2,2)*imageA(1,2);
0 0 imageB(1,2) imageB(2,2) 0 1 -imageB(1,2)*imageA(2,2) -imageB(2,2)*imageA(2,2);
imageB(1,3) imageB(2,3) 0 0 1 0 -imageB(1,3)*imageA(1,3) -imageB(2,3)*imageA(1,3);
0 0 imageB(1,3) imageB(2,3) 0 1 -imageB(1,3)*imageA(2,3) -imageB(2,3)*imageA(2,3);
imageB(1,4) imageB(2,4) 0 0 1 0 -imageB(1,4)*imageA(1,4) -imageB(2,4)*imageA(1,4);
0 0 imageB(1,4) imageB(2,4) 0 1 -imageB(1,4)*imageA(2,4) -imageB(2,4)*imageA(2,4)];
B = [imageB(1,1); imageB(2,1); imageB(1,2); imageB(2,2); imageB(1,3); imageB(2,3); imageB(1,4); imageB(2,4)];

result = pinv(A)*B;
end
```

i want to build now the transform
[x' y' 1] = A*[X Y 1];
i have figured out that i would need to use repmat, but i can't seem to get to the real syntax without loops.
what's the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: This is a _programming question_ about MATLAB, and not a signal processing question. It should be migrated to a programming site on SE. If not, it should be closed here.

Comment: @DilipSarwate please look at my last question.it's an image processing question

Comment: Your _last_ question as of now reads _"... i can't seem to get to the real syntax without loops. what's the most efficient way to do it?"_ In what sense is this a **signal processing** question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A projective transform has the form of

$ x' = \frac {a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}}{a_{13}x+a_{23}y+a_{33}} \\ 
  y' = \frac {a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}}{a_{13}x+a_{23}y+a_{33}}
$

Where the coefficients are defined up to some scale factor. One of the ways to ensure a constant scale factor is to set $a_{33}=1$. One easy way to think about it is to use the homogenous coordinates:

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} x'\\y'\\S\end{array} \right) =  
\left( \begin{array}{ccc} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\     a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\end{array} \right) 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc} x\\y\\1\end{array} \right) 
$

These coordinates are defined up to scale. That is,

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} x'/S\\y'/S\\1\end{array} \right) \equiv 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc} x'\\y'\\S\end{array} \right)$

Thus, in your case you should do: (Assuming that `x` and `y` are column vectors, and `A` is the transpose of the matrix that I described above:

```
  XY = A * [x y ones(size(x))];
  XY(:,1) = XY(:,1)./XY(:,3);
  XY(:,2) = XY(:,2)./XY(:,3);
```

Comment: thank for the answer ,i can share my whole code if that helps. let's a assume i have a 256X256 grayscale picture (imageB) i want to map into a bigger picture (imageA). so when i use the above code what i'll get will be X=256X256 and so will be Y=256X256. so the code for that will need to different than what you wrote, correct?

Comment: @Androidy, if you want to map images you should also add interpolation and use inverse transform. You should really take a look at how Matlab does it. Check out http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4804/how-do-i-resample-an-image-to-a-rotated-grid/4808#4808

Comment: my problem is not the image processing knowledge but more of a Matlab syntax, should i post this in StackOverFlow? i'm going to use bilinear interpolation, but before that i need to apply the inverse transform.

Comment: @Androidy, sorry, but I don't understand your problem. Can you please describe it better, including a reproducible code/ example?

Comment: i have added my full code. and some more explanations thanks.

Comment: let's assume i have 4 source x,y coords and 4 destination coords. how do i find the coefficiants. we can assume a33=1.

Comment: @Androidy, that is a totally different question. I think you should ask it separately.